# Java array[2] reference to array[0] but serialNo increments1

Tags: java, arrays, oop, object

I have a java program that models a tv and has stuff like power, channel, volume etc. It also has a unique Serial number that is automatically set (increments 1)

However, for my last array item array[2] I need to referernce my array[0] doing this works but my serialNo is no longer unique and just increments 1 (acts like a new tv has been created)

Comment: There are no references to variables in Java. `array[0] = array[2];` means that the value stored in variable at index 2 of object referenced by `array` is stored in the variable at index 0 of the object referenced by `array`.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem lies in the usage of

```
public static int serialNo() {
 return serialNo++;
}
```

- Each time you call this method, you increment the content of the static field.
- There is no direct relation between a TV and its serial number.

I suggest that you create a private field serialNumber in the TV class and  assign e.g. in the constructor serialNo to serialNumber and then increment.

Answer (score 0):

`serialNo` is static member of `Tv` class, this is what Oracle's [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html) says about statics.

> Fields that have the static modifier in their declaration are called
>   static fields or class variables. They are associated with the class,
>   rather than with any object. Every instance of the class shares a
>   class variable, which is in one fixed location in memory. Any object
>   can change the value of a class variable, but class variables can also
>   be manipulated without creating an instance of the class.

In this case, `serialNo` is not really associated with any object. So, there won't be something like `serialNo of the reference at array[2]` in this code.

Now, coming back to the question, you have a for loop that increments serial number as shown below:

```
for (int i = 0; i < tvDetails.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(SERIAL_NO + "\t\t" + tvDetails[0].serialNo() + "\n");
```

It executes `tvDetails.length` times (3) ad hence, the number gets incremented. If you don't want it to be incremened there then you need to make a couple of changes:

- Remove `return serialNo++;` from `serialNo()` method and just return serialNo:

  `public static int serialNo() {
      return serialNo;
  }`
- Increment serialNo in Tv's constructor, e.g.:

  `public Tv(boolean tvPower, int channel, int volumeLevel) {
      this.tvPower = tvPower;
      this.channel = channel;
      this.volumeLevel = volumeLevel;
      serialNo++;
  }`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Although trying to implement it, now seems the serialNo is all set to 1 (See my code from original question) and would just like the second ArrayIndex to be the same as array[0]. So the array[0] (tv1) and array[1] (tv2) both have unique serialNumbers but array[2] uses array[0]. Any suggestions how to fix. Thank you!

Comment: `tvDetails[2] = tvDetails[0];` means they both are pointing to the same object. So, there are only 2 tv objects and 3 references, with 2 pointing to the same object. If you want `tvDetails[2]` to have unique serial number then you need to do `tvDetails[2] = new Tv(true, 1, 97);`

Comment: Yeah thanks I understand now. Although my array needs to hold 3, whereby 2 tvs are created, then for the last position it should store a reference to the first tv which would be at index[0] Therefore the first and second tv need to have a unique serialNo, but then because the third item is a reference to the first tv that should obviously have the same serialNo as the firstTv

Comment: Yes. Also, `serialNo` is independent of the object as its static. If you want to have unique serialNo per object then you can declare non static member (like volUp, volDown), assign current value of static serialNo (in constructor) and increment static count.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

```
public static int serialNo() {
  return serialNo++;
}
```

This violates the SRP, the Single Responsibility Principle, by doing four things:
* Initializes an instance's `serialNo`,
* Generates a global "next serial no",
* Reports the global serial no, and
* Reports the instance's serial no, impossible for a static member.

Don't use the same name for different things.

```
public class Tv {
private static int universalSerial; // not thread-safe

public static int getUniversalSerial() {
  return universalSerial;
}

static int dispenseUniversalSerial() {
  return universalSerial++;
}

private final int serial;

public Tv () {
  this.serial = dispenseUniversalSerial();
}

public int getSerial() {
  return serial;
}

@Override public boolean equals(Object other) {
  if (this == other) { return true; }
  if (! (other instanceof Tv)) { return false; }
  Tv otherTv = (Tv) other;
  return serial == otherTv.serial;
}

@Override public int hashCode() {
  return serial;
}

@Override public String toString() {
  return "Tv " + serial;
}
}
```

Notice how the four tasks are split up between static and instance behaviors. Notice how the different names label different things. Notice the elimination of name parts like `No` that indicate implementation. Notice the coordinated overrides of the Big Three methods, `equals`, `hashCode`, and `toString`. Notice the lack of override for the fourth member of the Big Three, `compareTo`. That's deliberate. Notice the lack of thread safety. Notice that the instance `serial` field is final.

All of those decisions have purpose, and are boilerplate for value classes. The example implementation here is bog standard for non-thread-safe, non-comparable value classes with a factory. You should be able to code one of these up in about 10 minutes. It's a great kata to practice it.

Comment: Yeah great work here, though I would just like to fix my small error atm, and not worry about all this extra stuff. Any solutions to my question? Thanks.

Comment: This answer is a solution to your question. If you ever plan to use your `Tv` class then "all this stuff" isn't "extra". Anyway, how do you know what not to use until you understand the example? Sure, there may be parts you don't need. Figure it out. You don't need us to spoonfeed you. And you won't be able to use any answers you can't bother yourself to understand. It's worth the not very large effort. You'll get a very large payback for the picayune investment to understand a fully-formed response with everything you need.

Comment: alright, alright, calm it down guys! I do thank you for the answer you provided though on a simple program like this I was just looking for a simple solution to my logic error and code structure and not one that may be of 'professional standard' which I do not require at the moment, thats all!